# Update a "UseContext array" fail to re-render/generate a new component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Using context to store an array and try to array.map to generate a list of component, but the UI did not re-render to show all the component.

**Program background:**

I have a context which contain a array and the UI will have a "Add" button.

**My Goal:**

1. when user press "Add"
2. array in context will be pushed a new value in it
3. UI will be rerender and generate a new component

**My problem:**

I have try to use useState to store the array and that is completely OK since, once I update the list using setArray, that will triggle re-render and display a new component.

However, when I try to use useContext, the page will not be rerendered.

1. Should I still use useState to perform my goal? (then I have to manage 2 varible which are the context and state, I think that is a dummy way to work on it.)
2. is there any other method to achievel my goal?

Here is the sandbox demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-field-ur748?file=/src/App2.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component subscribing the context will re-render only when the `value` provided by the context changes.

Pushing the value to the list will not work here, because the reference of the `list` Array will not change when you push . So you should use the combination of state and context in this case .

Maintain the list in the state and pass it along with the state updater `setList` as the value to the Provider.

```
const [ list , setList ] = React.useState([121, 123])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[list, setList]}>
      <App2 />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
```

Now update the state from the component which subscribes the context .

```
export default function App2() {
  const [list, setList] = useContext(UserContext);
  const buttonOnClick = () => {
      setList(prevList => [...prevList, 321])
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={buttonOnClick}>Add</button>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Is it possible not to change the context object to useState to achievel the goal?

Comment: I don't think there is any to my knowledge . You not only want the context to provide a updated value but what you need is also a re-render to render the new items in the list . Any the only way to trigger a re-render in react is to change the state or props .

Comment: Let me recap your answers to see whether my understanding is correct or not. Since pushing a new value in context array will not change the reference. React will not consider as state or props change, therefore there is no re-render. So, I have to make use of both context and usestate to perform the task

Comment: Yes that's correct ! Because of the reference check its not a good practice to mutate an array or object .

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! You saved me one hell of a headache :)